# jQuery Possiblity to prevent showing popup on another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, popupwindow

I am working on problem with showing popup. I would like to prevent showing popup on another screen when I clicked hypertext link.
I have popup with cookie policy and on the bottom of this popup there is redirection to privacy policy which is another page and on this page I would not like to have this popup.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax( "/legal/privacy-policy" )
    .done(function() {
        $(".cc-cookies").hide();
    })
}
```

I wroted this function but it is closing popup also on current page. Please help!

Comment: If the browser is navigating to another page then any JavaScript code you want to affect that page would have to be on that other page.

Comment: Simple solution is check the current page url before showing the popup